# Is there any possibility to use @DataMongoTest in Spock tests?

Tags: spring-boot-test

I want to use `@DataMongoTest` annotation in my Spock integration tests in order to use embedded in-memory Mongo. Using it with standard @SpringBootTest doesn't work. Is there any possibility to do that?

I can see that this annotation is connected with `SpringRunner` / JUnit, but maybe there is some workaround?

Comment: Why do you need both annotations? `@DataMongoTest` slices your Spring Boot config so that only repository level + embeded mongo is autoconfigured.
If you need whole application loaded in test - just use `@SpringBootTest` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` (will load embeded mongo as well)

Comment: You can use `@AutoConfigureDataMongo` along with `@SpringBootTest`